# How to detect iniTeX?

Tags: xetex, compiling, format-files, initex

How can I detect, from within a LaTeX document class, if the engine was started with `-ini` or not? I’m using XeTeX if that matters.

Comment: Only by proxy (checking catcodes for `{` and `}`, for example) unless you are using LuaTeX, but perhaps this is an X-Y question: is there a  wider context?

Comment: @JosephWright I’m basically trying to avoid an error if `\dump` is called in a regular run. I’m building a document class for the department but it loads a lot of packages and I want to support precompiling to a format, but I don’t want the end users to have to modify something inside the class if they use the format or not. If I can detect `iniTeX` then I can just make sure not to `\dump`

Comment: see how mylatex or mylatexformat handle that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, they don’t appear to that I could see. They always generate a format, and then gobble the preamble fully or partially on future runs. I’m trying not to gobble the preamble.

Comment: yes but documents written for mylatex, either dump or not  depending on the context which is not completely urelated